# Передать шаблон std::array в другой шаблон

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Шаблон std::vector передать получается:

```
template <class T, template<class U, class = allocator<U> >class Seq > 
class A{
    Seq<T> vect;
};

A<int, vector> a;
```

А как передать шаблон std::array? На все мои попытки компилятор ругается

Answer (score 0):

А зачем так себя ограничивать? :)

Вот такой вариант не годится?

```
template <class T, class Seq >
class A
{
    Seq vect;
};

A<int, vector<int>> a;
A<int, array<int,10>> b;
```

Как вариант, чтоб дважды `int` не писать -

```
template <class Seq, class T = typename Seq::value_type>
class A
{
    Seq vect;
    T i;
};

A<vector<int>> a;
A<array<int,10>> b;
```